# Calculate distance between 2 cells in a unidimensional array

Tags: arrays, math, vector, grid, distance

I have a unidimensional array. Each array position corresponds to a cell.

```
private Cell[] _cells = new Cell[size];
```

I also have the dimensions of the grid where these cells are placed.

```
private Vector2 _gridSize = new Vector2(x, y);
```

Just with that, I have to calculate how many cells are between two different indexes (See the image to have a visual example of what I'm referring to). Which operation I have to compute?

Example image:
[image: Example image >]

Searched result:
[image: Searched result >]

Thank you community!

Edit: The relationship is like the example below.

```
Array { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

Dimentions { x = 3,  y = 2 }

Grid :
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

- The distance between `5` and `2` will be `1`.
- The distance between `5` and `4` will be `1`.
- The distance between `0` and `2` will be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

If `diffX` is the absolute value of the difference between the X coordinate of the first and the second cell and `diffY` is the absolute value of the difference between the Y coordinates of the first and the second cell, your answer is `result = diffX + diffY`.

If you want to find the (X,Y) coordinates of the cell in which the value `a` resides,
given `x` as the number of rows and `y` as the number of columns,
you can use this simple algorithm:

```
for (i=0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
    if (array[i] == a){
        yOfA = i / x;
        xOfA = i % x;
    } 
}
```

Remember that `xOfA` represents the column where `a` resides, while `yOfA` is the row, as you showed in your question.